# Cloudflare displaying cached CSS in-line?

Tags: cache

I recently enabled CloudFlare on my domain, and when I make HTML statements like this:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The CSS gets displayed in-line, like this:

```
<style>body{padding-top:40px}span.light{font-weight:lighter!important}span.title{font-size:60px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:-1px;color:inherit}</style>
```

When I update the file via FTP, the changes are not reflected, which leads me to believe that this is a caching issue.

Is this due to CloudFlare? If so, how do I disable the behavior?

**EDIT** I also came to the conclusion that caching is behind the behavior after being able to see changes in the page after re-naming the CSS file.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36276/files-not-refreshing-after-uploaded-and-overwritten-via-ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this wasn't a CloudFlare caching issue, it was caused by Google's `mod_pagespeed` enabled on my DreamHost account's configuration page.

The externally-referenced CSS files stopped appearing inline after disabling this addon.

Answer (score 0):

Manually purge the cache in CloudFlare

https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22042092-how-do-i-purge-my-cache

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Are you running WordPress?

Comment: This has occurred in a separate WordPress install but it's also occurring in manually-generated pages.

Comment: I'd contact CloudFlare if you're paying for their service their support can tell you exactly what's going on.